# How to trim an Aggregator RSS feed?

Tags: feeds

Drupal core module Aggregator produces feed titles like:

One two three four five six seven, all good children go to heaven.

I want this displayed:

One two three four five six seven, all good children

How to get this done?

Someone hinted that the [Smart Trim](https://www.drupal.org/project/smart_trim) module offers this option but I can't get it working in combination with Aggregator and [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels). How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it using the [Views module](https://www.drupal.org/project/views). I create a View of "Aggregator item" type.

In my view, I display each field I want to see, and for the "Aggregator:Title" field configuration, in the "Rewrite results" section, I checked "Trim this field to a maximum length". There are options to set the maximum length, to add or not an ellipsis (...), to add or not a "Read more" link... See the picture for more details (it refers to the "Aggregator:Body" field, but it works the same way).

Hope that helps,

[image: Configure field: Aggregator: Body]

Comment: Thanks, Dinopmi, that's probably what I was looking for.

Comment: You're welcome! If you find my answer fits your needs, don't forget to mark it as "accepted", so that your question is not considered "unanswered" :)